# How to serialize an object to a list of one elements with gson

Tags: java, arrays, json, serialization, gson

I have some json string like this:

example1

`{
  "path":{
    "start":"abc"
  },
  "name":"Fork1"
}`

example2

`{
  "path":[{
    "start":"abc"
  },
  {
    "start":"def"
  }],
  "name":"Fork1"
}`

and I want to serialize with **one** JAVA object like this:

```
@Data
public static class ForkNode {
    private List<Path> path;
    private String name;
}

@Data
public static class Path {
    private String start;
}
new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, ForkNode.class)
```

but it will throw an exception 
`IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 2 column 11 path $.path`

So how do I treat the first example as a list of one elements? 
Or is there any way I can serialize two different types of json strings with one object?

Comment: you need to do a custom deserialization with typeAdapter for path. see https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good way to serialize two different types of json strings with **ONE** object.

For example 1, the Object should be like this:

```
@Data
public static class ForkNode {
    // only one path 
    private Path path;
    private String name;
}

@Data
public static class Path {
    private String start;
}
new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, ForkNode.class)
```

While For example 2, the Object should be like this:

```
@Data
public static class ForkNode {
    // several paths 
    private List<Path> path;
    private String name;
}

@Data
public static class Path {
    private String start;
}
new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, ForkNode.class)
```

In JSON:

- Objects are enclosed directly in curly brackets {} While JSON
- Arrays that are enclosed in square brackets [] inside JSON Objects.

One more thing, If you do really want to do that, I think you need to **implement a custom deserializer** by yourself. Please ref the doc of Gson.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by modify JsonObject.
I use this code to convent JsonObject to JsonArray, so I can deserializer it like JsonArray.

```
public void objectToArray(JsonObject jsonObject, String node) {
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonObject.get(node);
    if (jsonElement instanceof JsonObject) {
        JsonArray array = new JsonArray();
        array.add(jsonElement);
        jsonObject.remove(node);
        jsonObject.add(node, array);
    }
}
```